# PouchDB - Map reduce query not working with websql adapter

Tags: pouchdb

#### Issue

Map reduce query not working with websql adapter

#### Info

- Environment: Node.js
- Platform: Mac/Windows 10
- Adapter: WebSQL, HTTP
- Server: CouchDB

#### Reproduce

```
const PouchDB = require("pouchdb-core");
PouchDB
    .plugin(require("pouchdb-adapter-node-websql"))
    .plugin(require("pouchdb-adapter-http"))
    .plugin(require("pouchdb.mapreduce.noeval"))
    .plugin(require("pouchdb-replication"));

var websqlDB = new PouchDB("db_test.sql", { adapter: "websql" });
var serverDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/db_test");

async function test(db) {
    const itemView = {
        _id: "_design/item", views: {
            item: {
                map: function (doc) {
                    try {
                        emit(doc);
                    } catch (err) { }
                }.toString()
            }
        }
    };
    try { await db.put(itemView); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
    await  db.post({name: "name"});
    const docs = await db.query("item");
    return docs;
}

async function run() {
    console.log("query websql db");
    console.log(await test(websqlDB));

    console.log("query couch db");
    console.log(await test(serverDB));
}

run().then().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Output

```
query websql db
{ total_rows: 0, offset: 0, rows: [] }
query couch db
{ total_rows: 1,
  offset: 0,
  rows:
   [ { id: 'fa2e86f972cb38d80530b734bc00bf4d',
       key: [Object],
       value: null } ] }
```

It seems the query is not working with websql adapter. It returns nothing when I query on it. We notice this issue on both Mac and Windows platform. Here is the versions I use:

```
{
    "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite": "^2.0.5",
    "pouchdb-adapter-http": "^6.4.3",
    "pouchdb-adapter-node-websql": "^7.0.0",
    "pouchdb-core": "^6.4.3",
    "pouchdb-find": "^6.4.3",
    "pouchdb-replication": "^6.4.3",
    "pouchdb-upsert": "^2.2.0",
    "pouchdb.mapreduce.noeval": "^0.2.0"
}
```

Not sure whether it is my code issue or the websql actually is not able to work with map reduce query.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the pouchdb-adapter-node-websql on github, but if it is similar to the pouchdb-adapter-websql-core, it is no longer supported.

As a result, I found that the indexing will break on the first consumption of the index after an update.  Specifically the 'keys' option of the allDocs method was not working for me, which causes the getKeyValueDocs method of the pouchdb-abstract-mapreduce module to work incorrectly, returning all docs.  When the index is updated after this method, it results in all docs EXCEPT the updated doc being removed from the index.  As a result -- you will get nothing back in any query that doesn't include your last updated document.

I did find [this repository](https://github.com/kkbhav/pouchdb-adapter-rn-websql-core) which fixes pouchdb-adapter-websql-core for react-native.  It may also work for Cordova.